# Simple SQL Excel Count

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, distinct

My input is the following and would like to achieve the following output using MS Access and SQL statements. I have over 10,000 rows of "Machine name" and 1 million rows of "Serial #s" but would like to do a count of Serial #s based on Machine Name:

### Example

Input:

```
Machine Name    | Serial #
ALPHA0101       | K3332293
ALPHA0101       | L6569866
ALPHA0101       | R6889533
ALPHA0101       | H556565
ALPHA0101       | H353565
ALPHA0102       | W323232
ALPHA0102       | R656986
ALPHA0102       | I3232323
```

Expected Output:

```
Machine Name    | Count of Serial #s
ALPHA0101       | 5
ALPHA0102       | 3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged sql?

Comment: I"m using MS Access and attempting to use SQL Code within Access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT [Machine Name], COUNT(*) AS [Count of Serial #s]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [Machine Name]
```